# how to resolve domain name on local machine

Tags: linux, dns, localhost

I have a computer to use it as local DNS server.

I want:

- when it do not connect internet, so any request to this local server will redirect or resolve request domain to server ip.
- when it connect internet, it will resolve request domain as normal DNS function.

So, do I need anything or config something? please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand that exactly do you want
If you have DNS server installed why not to use in all the time?

you may configure `forwarders` section in your `named.conf`

```
    forwarders {
            8.8.8.8;
            8.8.4.4;
    };
```

In this case your domains will be managed by your DNS server, and all other requests will be forwarded to external servers and cached for future usage :)
more details [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: use my own dns server is ok, and I installed dns server on the same local server. But, my local server sometime will be offline, and don't connect internet. It only work on LAN network, that means only local computers can connect to this local server. so I need some way to check
-when it do not connect internet, so any request to this local server will redirect or resolve request domain to server ip.
-when it connect internet, it will resolve request domain as normal DNS function.

Comment: It is still hard to understand that you are mean. but I will try, you may configure your client to put requests to two dns servers. First one is yours and second is some external server. And if your server will be switched off clients will put requests to external server. But if your server will operate without internet it will send false negative answers to clients and clients will not try to connect external servers.